# SDL + SDL_TTF: How do you render text in SDL+SDL_TTF? (C++)

Tags: sdl, truetype

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to render text in SDL with TTF to an SDL window. I'm a little new to C++ and would like this explained in a bit of a 'newbie' way. (with some example code, if possible?)

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?  What do you have (code-wise)?  What didn't work?

Comment: Hell i don't even understand my own code anymore. But pretty much this:

  SDL_Color fontcolor = {fgR,fgG,fgB,fgA};
  SDL_Color fontbgcolor = {bgR, bgG, bgB, bgA};
  SDL_Surface* text;
 
  if (quality == solid) resulting_text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(fonttodraw, text, fontcolor);
  else if (quality == shaded) resulting_text = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(fonttodraw, text, fontcolor, fontbgcolor);
  else if (quality == blended) resulting_text = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fonttodraw, text, fontcolor);
 
  return text;

Comment: Have a look at http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson07/index.php

Comment: Now http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example.  Make sure that you have arial.ttf, or your truetype font of choice in your directory.  You will need to link with -lSDL -lSDL_ttf.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"

SDL_Surface* screen;
SDL_Surface* fontSurface;
SDL_Color fColor;
SDL_Rect fontRect;

SDL_Event Event;

TTF_Font* font;

//Initialize the font, set to white
void fontInit(){
        TTF_Init();
        font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 12);
        fColor.r = 255;
        fColor.g = 255;
        fColor.b = 255;
}

//Print the designated string at the specified coordinates
void printF(char *c, int x, int y){
        fontSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, c, fColor);
        fontRect.x = x;
        fontRect.y = y;
        SDL_BlitSurface(fontSurface, NULL, screen, &fontRect);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize the SDL library with the Video subsystem
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE);

    //Create the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320, 480, 0, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    //Initialize fonts
    fontInit();

    //Print to center of screen
    printF("Hello World", screen->w/2 - 11*3, screen->h/2);

    do {
        // Process the events
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            switch (Event.type) {

                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch (Event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    // Escape forces us to quit the app
                        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                            Event.type = SDL_QUIT;
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    SDL_Delay(10);
    } while (Event.type != SDL_QUIT);

    // Cleanup
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```